# Class derivation on the fly - Visitor Pattern

Tags: java, derived-class, visitor-pattern

I would like to create visitor pattern in such a way

```
public interface Visitable<T>{
   public void accept(T visitor);
}

public interface SomeBusinessService implements Visitable<SomeVisitor>{

  public void mtd1();
  public void mtd2();
}

public abstract class SomeBusinessBean1 implements SomeBusinessService {
   public void mtd1(){}
   public void mtd2(){}
} 

public abstract class SomeBusinessBean2 implements SomeBusinessService {
   ...
}
```

and so on

then I would like to create a factory

```
public class SomeBusinessServiceFactory {
   public SomeBusinessService createService
                 (Class<? extends SomeBusinessService> clazz ){
      //do some stuff to create appropriate class derivation on the fly
     // that will have accept() method implemented 
   }
}
```

and I could invoke it in the following way

```
SomeBusinessService  service = 
    SomeBusinessServiceFactory.createService(SomeBusinessBean1.class);
```

With this approach I would't have to create comman abstract class for all  beans that 
implement Visitor interface accept() method.

This solution could also be used in  situations where we would like to have a common behaviour of specific methods depending on service factory per class hierarchy.

Is there any way to do that with standard jdk or maybe I need to use external tools like cglib or maybe what I'm saying is rubbish and we can achive that goal in some other way.

Tx in advanced

Comment: Just for clarificatin: `Visitor` and `Visitable` are "the same" and it's a typo in the question or do you have two different interfaces?

Comment: Usually a `Visitor` represents something that can visit `Visitable` classes.

Comment: Sorry my bad I ment implements Visitable. Visitor class would have only visit() methods with appropriate class as an input argument

Comment: Isn't this the kind of thing annotations are intended to be used for?

Comment: How exacly would you like to solve that via annotations because I don't fully understand it. What I would like to have is a common behaviour of several method in class hierarchy depending on the factory method. So for instance if I create another factory implementation it could implement abstract method in some other way.  So it will be consistent with open-close principle. I want to avoid if-else driven development.

Comment: I haven't delved deeply into this, but apt and annotations are supposed to allow you to generate classes at compile-time. Almost certainly easier than doing so at runtime. See [Getting started with APT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html)

Comment: I will have a closer look on apt  however I feel a litte bit reluctant to that approach since I will end up with bunch of unnecessery generated class-files instead of something like dynamic proxy Proxy.newInstance() which is unfortunatelly only available for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to create a class instance from its class object than have a look at the java reflection api.

```
clazz.newInstanze();
```

or

```
clazz.getConstructors(...).newInstance(...);
```

Comment: Well I can't do that because my deriviations are abstract classes that is the point I want to create anonymous class on the fly but I want to determine which class should be extended in the runtime rather than compilation time.

Comment: @Marcin Michalski what should this anonymous class do?

Comment: well In this specific case anonymous class are Visitable implementations that does not have unnecessary class method  accept() implemented. I would like to achieve something similar as it was in EJB2.x entity beans where properties of the entity bean were abstract getters/setters and container was responsible for extending entity bean class during deployment time. I have started reading about ASM library and maybe that will help me to sort it out. As a result I could end up with a mechanism that could determine in the runtime common behavior to a group of classes hierarchy